# React Native Maps - Marker onPress calling multiple events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm facing one problem when a try to call more than one event in onPress Marker event.

The idea is:

- load the markers into the map
- center the marker (clicked)
- update a state based on marker selected
- call an expression to open a bottom sheet

This example works well, the first and the second points

```
<Marker
key={i}
image={require('../assets/marker.png')}
onPress={() => 
  mapView.animateToRegion({
    latitude: Number(dev.lat),
    longitude: Number(dev.lng),
    latitudeDelta: 0.0432, 
    longitudeDelta: 0.0423
    },300)

}
calloutAnchor={{
    x: 0.6,
    y: 0,
}}
coordinate={{
  latitude: Number(dev.lat),
  longitude: Number(dev.lng),
}}
>
```

This example works fine calling only the function animateToRegion, but if replaced for another function to call others events this specific event doesn't work as below.

```
const bs = React.createRef()

function goto (index) {
    bs.current.snapTo(index) // reference to bottomsheet
}

function loadGaz(dev) {
    setSelectedGas(dev) // state update
}

function mapCenter (dev)  {
   mapView.animateToRegion({
      latitude: Number(dev.lat),
      longitude: Number(dev.lng),
      latitudeDelta: 0.0432, 
      longitudeDelta: 0.0423
   },300)     
}

function x (dev) {
   mapCenter (dev) // center marker into screen
   loadGaz(dev) // state to data into bottomsheet
   goto(0) //show bottom sheet
}

// If I remove others functions (loadGaz and goto) everything works fine.

<Marker
  key={i}
  image={require('../assets/marker.png')}
  onPress={() => x(dev)}
  calloutAnchor={{
    x: 0.6,
    y: 0,
  }}
  coordinate={{
    latitude: Number(dev.lat),
    longitude: Number(dev.lng),
  }}
>
```

Well, I imagine that I made some mistakes and I'd to thank you for your support..

Thanks community..